# Convert Integer to Single

Tags: vb.net, integer, ctype

I am using the Graph Control made by a user named "Aeonhack" in my .NET application. When adding, let's say, a point with the size `9`, it has to be a Single like `9.0F`.

So I want a function that converts an Integer like `9` into a single like `9.0F`.

The normal `CType` won't work, and I also tried:

```
Private Function IntToSingle(ByVal Number As Integer) As Single
    Return CType(Number & ".0F", Single)
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    GraphConnections.AddValue(IntToSingle(7))
End Sub
```

This gives me this error:

> Conversion from string "7.0F" to type 'Single' is not valid.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You don't need the ".0F"

Answer (score 7):

Use `Convert.ToSingle`:

```
Convert.ToSingle(Number)
```

Or just `CType`, without weird string concatenation:

```
CType(Number, Single)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the confusion is with `7.0F`. That is not the same thing as the string `"7.0F"`.

[Per Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xay7978z.aspx)

> Appending the literal type character F to a literal forces it to the
>   single data type.

You could simply use the `F` to force a double literal to be a single data type.

```
GraphConnections.AddValue(7.0F)
```

If, however, you receive an integer variable, then you would need to convert or cast it to a single as suggested by @MarcinJuraszek.

```
dim point As Integer = 7

GraphConnections.AddValue(Convert.ToSingle(point))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to convert to a single: `CSng(9)`, though I think this only works in VB.NET.